# reCaptcha usability? give up after 15 minutes verifying you are a human

Tags: web-applications, recaptcha

reCaptcha usability? give up after 15 minutes verifying you are a human.

```
Check all cars
then check all crosswalks
then check all firehyants
then check all storefront,
again
then check all crosswalks,
on and on ...
```

After 15 minutes, I had to give up "Sign Up" using reCaptcha.  Is reCaptcha still usable?

A more smart way should be used. Looking at images is very time-consuming and requires a lot of patience. Did not show a message after spending 15 minutes? Users do not have such patience. Not good to human eyes for staring at screen for a long time.

Adding a security level parameter would be helpful. For example, for financial app, it should be high. For most apps, it can be set to medium or low if app owners think that hackers are not interested in their apps.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is more of a suggestion than a question. yes the reCaptcha can be frustrating sometimes and cud really use the low security example like you purposed.

Google uses IP addresses and cookies to recognize you mainly, also the position of your click on checkbox (yes, coz bots click the exact center of checkbox) many many other indications. you can check some below points if they help:

- Check your IP or network for any issues
- make sure you have cookies enabled
- Stop using VPN or proxy servers
- try using Google public DNS
- dont search illegal queries
- Slowdown clicks, no rapid firing
- dont send automated queries

you can read more about this here: https://www.webnots.com/fix-im-not-a-robot-captcha-issue-in-google-search/